# Retrieving a specific php variable using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I started venturing on ajax and its coolness.

I managed to GET all the data from the ajax request but I wonder if you can request for a specific php variable to be retrieved.

I have the following code on HTML:

```
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="textdiv">
<div id="counter"></div>
</div>
<script>
$("#textdiv").hover(function(){
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data){
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = data;
            });
});
</script>
```

And on the ajax.php I have the following:

```
<?php
$kate = "Kate is here";
echo $kate;
$jack = "Jack is here";
echo $jack;
?>
```

Of course hovering on textdiv now I get both data however I have the following questions:
1) Is it possible to request only $jack and how would the function look like?
2) Is my code a true ajax request vs $.ajax({...

Thank you,
Oliver

Comment: Do not `echo $kate`?

Comment: I understand if you don't echo, you won't get that specific data, however, lets say you have 10 variable in php, and sometimes you want to get one variable and sometimes you want to get the others, how would configure the $.get to only ask for that variable

Comment: AJAX will return everything PHP echos, so you either need to control what is echoed or control what you get back in the AJAX call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8"');

echo json_encode([
  'kate' => "Kate is here",
  'jack' => "Jack is here",
]);
```

And then use:

```
$("#textdiv").hover(function(){
    $.get('ajax.php', function(data){
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = data.jack;
    });
});
```

---

To answer your question in the comment: You can't.

Javascript has no notion of the variables that exist in your php-script. Your tool of communication is a simple http request which ultimately is a simple exchange of text.

As such the server (php script) needs to prepare that text in a way that is readable by the client (javascript).